# Aternativa a fgetc C++

Tags: c++, fstream

Hola buenas tardes estoy teniendo un pequeño problema: tengo que crear un archivo .txt donde meta un sudoku de 9x9. Por ejemplo este:

> ```
> - 5 - 8 - - - 7 4
> - - 1 5 - 7 - - -
> - 7 - - - 4 5 - -
> 2 - - 4 - - - - 9
> - 6 - - 8 - 3 5 -
> 1 - - - - - - - 7
> - - - - - 8 - 3 -
> - - - 2 - 9 6 - 8
> 8 1 - - - 3 - 9 -
> ```

El problema es que al recorrer la fila me detecte los "-" y me los cambie por cero " 0 ".Busque en google y lo que puedo hacer es poner el fgetc que me lo detecta y lo cambia. Pero me sale error en "fgetc".

Luego me di cuenta que Eso aparecía solo cuando el archivo era del tipo File archivo; pero yo estoy utilizando "ifstream archivo;" para su lectura. ¿Hay alguna biblioteca o una palabra alternativa a "fgetc" que puede utilizar en ifstream?

Cabe añadir que añadí las bibliotecas de fstream y iostream Aquí dejo la imagen si no se puede ver bien el código:
Código:

```
void sudoku1(){
    Sudoku sudoku1;
    int sudoku[9][9];
    string linea;
    int i, j;
    //creo el fichero se dalida
    ofstream fs; //ofstream me crea el archivo
    // Introducimos el sudoku1
    fs.open("Sudoku1.txt", ios::out); // abrimos el archivo en modo lectura
    if(fs.fail()){
        cout << "Sucedió un problema con el Sudoku 1. "<<endl;
        exit(1); 
    }else{
        fflush(stdin); // vacío el buffer para poder introducir mas datos
        fs << "- - 8 4 9 - 6 - -"<<endl;
        fs << "6 - 4 6 - 3 2 - -"<<endl;
        fs << "- - - - - - - - 7"<<endl;
        fs << "- 8 - 2 - - 1 - -"<<endl;
        fs << "- - 1 - - 8 5 7 -"<<endl;
        fs << "7 - 6 5 - 4 3 - 9"<<endl;
        fs << "8 6 - - - - - - -"<<endl;
        fs << "- 1 - - 2 - - 5 8"<<endl;
        fs << "- 4 - - 5 - - - -"<<endl;
    }
    //Cerramos el fichero para posteriormente abrirlo y leerlo
    fs.close();
    // LECTURA DEL ARCHIVO
   ifstream archivo;
    archivo.open("Sudoku1", ios::in); // abro el archivo en modo lectura

    while(! archivo.eof()){ // mientras que el archivo no sea el final
        char raya;
        while (raya = fgetc(archivo) !EOF) { // si seproduce un error en 
            la lectura
            // la funcion devuelve EOf
            // fgetc da la informacion de un solo caracter en este caso de 
                la " - "
            if( raya == '-'){
                sudoku[i][j]=0;
            }else{

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pon el código, si "*no se adapta*" ya lo corregiremos. Para poner código pégalo en la pregunta y pulsa el botón con las llaves (`{}`) en la interfaz de edición.

Comment: ya añadí el codigo

Answer (score 1):

La funcón [`std::fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgetc) pertenece a las cabeceras de C, espera recibir un puntero a `FILE` pero tú le estás pasando una referencia a `std::ifstream` por lo que es normal que falle.

Lo que tienes que hacer es leer con el operador de extracción con formato (`>>`):

```
/* Abrir archivo y comprobar que no hubo errores al abrirlo,
todo en una sola linea. */
if (std::ifstream i{"Sudoku1"})
{
    char valor{}; // Valor que vamos a leer

    /* Leemos dentro de 'valor' si hay un fallo al leer (por ejemplo: que no hay más archivo
    para leer) saldrá del bucle */
    while (i >> valor)
    {
        // hacer cosas...
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/P1vsCXYvfI62xeTL).